# How to generate hyperlinks to .htm files in a directory in Powershell?

Tags: html, url, powershell, hyperlink

I would like to scan a directory for .htm files and then generate hyperlinks to those .htm files and output the result to a new HTML document. What is the best way to achieve this?

So far I have this:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\test1\*.htm" -Recurse -Force |
  ConvertTo-Html -Fragment FullName, Name `
    -PreContent '<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>' `
    -PostContent '</body></html>' |
  % { $_ -replace '<th>.*</th>','<th>Files</th>' `
         -replace '<td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td>',
                  '<td><a href="$1">$2</a> $3</td>'

  } | Set-Content "C:\$env:COMPUTERNAME-$(Get-Date -f dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss).htm"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\*.htm" -Recurse -Force |
  ConvertTo-Html -Fragment FullName, Name, LastWriteTime `
    -PreContent '<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>' `
    -PostContent '</body></html>' |
  % { $_ -replace '<th>.*</th>','<th>Files</th>' `
         -replace '<td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td>',
                  '<td><a href="$1">$2</a> $3</td>'

  } | Set-Content "C:\$env:COMPUTERNAME-$(Get-Date -f dd-MM-yyyy).htm"
```

Comment: I'm struggling to adopt the code above to get it to generate .htm files. I trying the following version of the code above:**Get-ChildItem "C:\*.htm" -Recurse -Force |
$b =  ConvertTo-Html -Fragment Name, LastWriteTime `
    -PreContent '<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>' `
    -PostContent '</body></html>' |
  % { $_ -replace '<th>.*</th>','<th>Files</th>' `
         -replace '<td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td>',
                  '<td><a href="$1">$2</a> $3</td>'

  }
$b | Set-Content c:\"$env:computername-$(get-date -f dd-MM-yyyy)".htm**

Comment: This doesn't work: `... | $b = ...`. You can't pipe into an assignment statement. I added `Set-Content` to my answer.

Comment: thanks for your reply. now the code is generating .htm file but it doesn't insert hyperlinks to the scanned files. I'm new to the Powershell, so don't really know where is the problem here. appreciate your help.

Comment: Please show your updated code. Don't post it as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: I've updated the code in the question. As I mentioned I don't really know where is the problem in the code.

Comment: You're enumerating `*.html`, not `*.htm`. Change that to `*.htm` if your HTML files have that extension. Or use `*.htm*` if you have both extensions.

Comment: Great, one step closer. Now generated HTML document has all the names of the scanned files, but it doesn't display them as hyperlinks. I've updated the code in the question.

Comment: You omitted `LastWriteTime` from your selection list, so the regular expression that creates the hyperlink doesn't match anymore.

Comment: Thanks! Now the hyperlinks are generated.

Comment: An cleaner alternate approach is mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652761/convert-a-list-of-urls-into-clickable-html-links-using-convertto-html

Comment: The above example works fine for me, ry to use:'<td><a href="$2">$2</a> $3</td>' instead of '<td><a href="$1">$2</a> $3</td>' and thanks @Ansgar for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

This could be right up your street, you would need to add a filter to the `Get-ChildItem` line though:
[Aaron Lerch Blog - Create Directory Table Of Contents With Powershell](http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2007/11/02/create-a-directory-table-of-contents-with-powershell/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm going to give it a go.