# How to modify this Powershell code so that hyperlinks will also work for HTML files in subdirectories?

Tags: html, powershell, hyperlink

The existing code scans IIS root and its sub-directories for .htm files and generates new .htm file with functioning hyperlinks to the .htm files in root directory only. Hyperlinks to the .htm files in the root sub-directories don't function properly, as it doesn't have the sub folder path included in the hyperlink.
I would like to modify my existing code so that hyperlinks to the .htm files in the sub-folders will also work.

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\inetpub\wwwroot" -Recurse -Force |
  ConvertTo-Html -Fragment Name, Name, LastWriteTime `
    -PreContent '<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>' `
    -PostContent '</body></html>' |
  % { $_ -replace '<th>.*</th>','<th>Files</th>' `
         -replace '<td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td>',
                  '<td><a href="$1">$2</a> $3</td>'

  } | Set-Content "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.htm"
```

[image]

Comment: Is it really that hard to just copy/paste working code from an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17472295/1630171)?

Comment: the answer produced following hyperlink (c:/inetpub/wwwroot/NH0000/NH0000-09-07-2013-03-19.htm) which doesn't work for web server. remember this is web server, so the proper link should look something like this (172.16.x.x/NH0000/NH0000-09-07-2013-03-19.htm). Now how to generate such hyperlink is the question.

Comment: I appreciate your help, any new suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need to exchange the basedir in the URL (note: this is significant detail information, you shouldn't omit these things from your questions), something like this should work:

```
$basedir = 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot'
$exp     = [regex]::Escape($basedir)
$server  = 'http://172.16.x.x'

Get-ChildItem $basedir -Recurse -Force |
  select Name, LastWriteTime, 
    @{n="URL";e={$_.FullName -replace $exp, $server -replace '\\', '/'}} |
  ConvertTo-Html -Fragment URL, Name, LastWriteTime `
    -PreContent '<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>' `
    -PostContent '</body></html>' |
  % { $_ -replace '<th>.*</th>','<th>Files</th>' `
         -replace '<td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td>',
                  '<td><a href="$1">$2</a> $3</td>'
  } | Set-Content "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.htm"
```

The additional `select` instruction transforms `FullName` into a new property `URL` of the form `http://172.16.x.x/path/to/file`. Then `ConvertTo-Html` converts this new property and the passed-through properties `Name` and `LastWriteTime` into HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your code works great! hyperlinks for files in sub-folders are all functional.

Comment: Ansgar, I have additional question. is there a way to run the code above, for each sub-folder in the IIS root directory separately. I can put this as a separate question, if it's more convenient for you to answer. Thanks

Comment: @user2545794 That would have to be a separate question, yes. Please explain in that question how you want to process each folder, i.e. if you want separate output files for each folder (containing only the files in that folder) or whatever.

Comment: Sure I'll put as a separate question.

Comment: here is the additional [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567547/how-to-run-the-powershell-code-against-each-subfolder-that-is-in-the-iis-root-di)

Comment: I have one more question about your answer code above. I've put it as a separate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589319/how-to-modify-powershell-code-so-that-hyperlinks-are-only-created-for-the-files)