# How to run the powershell code against each subfolder that is in the IIS root directory?

Tags: powershell, each, subdirectory

I would like to run the powershell code below, against each sub-folder that is in the IIS root directory. The output should be separate .htm file for each sub-folder contents (containing only the files in that sub-folder). If you need me to clarify my question, just ask.

```
$basedir = 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot'
$exp     = [regex]::Escape($basedir)
$server  = 'http://172.16.246.76'

function Create-HtmlList($fldr) {
  Get-ChildItem $fldr -Force |
    select ...
    ...
  } | Set-Content "$fldr.htm"
}

# list files in $basedir:
Create-HtmlList $basedir

# list files in all subfolders of $basedir:
Get-ChildItem $basedir -Recurse -Force |
  ? { $_.PSIsContainer } |
  % {
    Create-HtmlList $_.FullName
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate folder-traversal (recursive) from file processing (non-recursive), e.g. like this:

```
$basedir = 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot'
$exp     = [regex]::Escape($basedir)
$server  = 'http://172.16.x.x'

function Create-HtmlList($fldr) {
  Get-ChildItem $fldr -Force |
    ? { -not $_.PSIsContainer } |
    select ...
    ...
  } | Set-Content "$fldr.htm"
}

# list files in $basedir:
Create-HtmlList $basedir

# list files in all subfolders of $basedir:
Get-ChildItem $basedir -Recurse -Force |
  ? { $_.PSIsContainer } |
  % {
    Create-HtmlList $_.FullName
  }
```

The output files will be put into the respective folder (named after the folder with the extension `.htm` appended). If you want a different name or location for the output files, you need to adjust the `Set-Content` line in the function `Create-HtmlList`.

Comment: I tried to run your crypt without modifications (except IP address). it gives the following error: An empty pipe element is not allowed.
`At H:\scrypts\GenHyperlinksInHtml_V2.ps1:9 char:6
+   } | <<<<  Set-Content "$fldr.htm"
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement` I'm not sure where I have to modify the code to get it right.

Comment: Of course you need to replace the ellipses (`...`) with the rest of the code that I left out for brevity. Please do some legwork yourself, will you?

Comment: I'm new to the powershel used it for just 9 days now. Sure, I'll play with the code and see if I gen get it working. I'll update the question as I progress.

Comment: It's not that difficult, really. All you need to do is replace what's between `select` and `Set-Content` in the new code with what's between `select` and `Set-Content` in the old code.