# Convert a list of URLs into clickable HTML links using ConvertTo-HTML

Tags: powershell

I have the function below that will create an HTML table however I want the values in my table to hyperlinks.

```
Function MyFunction{

clear-host
$item=$null
$hash = $null #hashTable

$hash =@{"Google.com" = "www.google.com"; "Yahoo" = "www.yahoo.com";"My Directory" ="C:\Users\Public\Favorites" ;"MSN" = "www.msn.com"}

ForEach($item in @($hash.KEYS.GetEnumerator())){
$hash | Sort-Object -Property name
}

$hash.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property Name |Select-Object Name, Value | ConvertTo-HTML | Out-File .\Test.html

}

MyFunction
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Small side note before we start: The `ForEach` seems pointless as it just outputs the sorted table for each element in the table. So that gets removed.

`ConvertTo-HTML` on its own is great for making table with PowerShell object but was we need is hyperlinks instead. `ConvertTo-HTML` does support calculated properties so at first it would seem easy to just make a formatted hyperlink.

```
ConvertTo-HTML -Property *,@{Label="Link";Expression={"<a href='$($_.Value)'>$($_.Name)</a>"}}
```

The small issue with that is `ConvertTo-Html` does some conversion on the string being sent to it which obfuscates our intention. Looking in the output file that is created we see the following for the Yahoo link:

```
<td>&lt;a href=&#39;www.yahoo.com&#39;&gt;Yahoo&lt;/a&gt;</td>
```

`ConvertTo-Html` made our text browser friendly which would be nice normally but hinders us now. Reading a blog from [PowerShell Magazine](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/03/25/pstip-fixing-the-output-of-convertto-html/) covers this issue by *decoding* the html before it is send to file.

```
Function MyFunction{
    clear-host
    $hash = @{"Google.com" = "www.google.com"; "Yahoo" = "www.yahoo.com";"My Directory" ="C:\Users\Public\Favorites" ;"MSN" = "www.msn.com"}
    $hash.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property Name | Select-Object Name, Value | 
        ConvertTo-HTML -Property *,@{Label="Link";Expression={"<a href='$($_.Value)'>$($_.Name)</a>"}}
}

$html = MyFunction 

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($html) | Out-File C:\temp\test.html
```

Using `[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode` converts values like `&lt;` back to what we want them to be. Have a look at the output

[image: Output]

Went looking to see if this has been asked before and there is a similar answer: [How to generate hyperlinks to .htm files in a directory in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471712/how-to-generate-hyperlinks-to-htm-files-in-a-directory-in-powershell). It is handled in a different way so im on the fence about marking this as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Matt, that seems to work, but let's say that I just want to disable some of the links, what can I do ?

Comment: What do you mean by disable? Choose not to add them to the table? Why should they be in the hashtable then if you dont want them? How do you decide what to disable? @loli

Comment: Because originally I am trying to add folder names to the hashtable i found in a scan Function, so there is a condition if the folder is found or not found.

Comment: If that was the case then you wouldnt be using a hashtable and as long as you have the right filters it sounds like you are just using `Get-ChildItem` and a where clause to get your folders. If you are still having issues make a new question since the scope would have changed.

Comment: Exactly I am using get-childitem -path "c:\program files\" and foreach and Add to hashtable.

Comment: Sorry to ask again , but is there any way to color the value of a string in HTML table if the value ="value defined" ? Thanks

Comment: It is solved   "<b style=""background-color:red"">this text in red !</b>".   -->

Thanks.