# Why is my powershell script escaping html brackets<>?

Tags: html, powershell

I am working on a script that is having issues outputting a link in powershell. This should output the System event log information with the last column a link to a Google search for more information on the specific error represented in that line.

### I currently have the following code:

```
$style = "<style>"
$style = $style + "Body{background-color:white;font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;}"
$style = $style + "Table{border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}"
$style = $style + "TH{border-width: 1px; padding: 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: #cccccc;}"
$style = $style + "TD{border-width: 1px; padding: 5px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; background-color: white;}"
$style = $style + "</style>"



$date = get-date -format M.d.yyyy

$now = get-date
$subtractDays = New-Object System.TimeSpan 30,0,0,0,0
$then = $Now.Subtract($subtractDays)

$systemErrors = Get-EventLog -Computername localhost -LogName system -After $then -Before $now -EntryType Error |
select EventID,Message,Source,TimeGenerated

$systemErrors | ConvertTo-HTML  -Property *,@{Label="More Information";Expression={"<a href='https://www.google.com/#q=Windows Error $($_.EventID)'>Find more...</a>"}} -head $style | Out-File "C:\Scripts\SystemEventLog-$date.html"
```

However, when I open the html document, the 'Find More...' link is outputting the escape characters for the brackets and single quotes, thus breaking the link.

[image: HTML not formatted properly]

I have searched and cannot find a resolution. I have tried switching quotes around, taking out the link and just leaving the code (to see if it was an issue with the other characters in the link), and moving things around to no avail.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking something like this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php - uri encode /uri decode maybe. I'll inline the screenshot for you not that it seems to help...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a list of URLs into clickable HTML links using ConvertTo-HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652761/convert-a-list-of-urls-into-clickable-html-links-using-convertto-html)

Comment: Bacon, that page is actually where I got some of this code as I am new to Powershell, but I may have missed that part. Looking into it now.

Comment: @BaconBits thanks for pointing out the part I missed.  I edited and added the following 


`$html = $systemErrors | ConvertTo-HTML  -Property *,@{Label="More Information";Expression={"<a href='https://www.google.com/#q=Windows Error $($_.EventID)'>Find more...</a>"}} -head $style  

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($html) | Out-File "C:\Scripts\SystemEventLog-$date.html" `