# HTML column as a link

Tags: html, powershell

I'm looking for a solution for making a html column in powershell as a link

[image: Image from table]

I have a HTML header in PS

```
$Header = @"
<style>
h1, h5, th { text-align: center; color:#0046c3; }
table { margin: auto; font-family: Segoe UI; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888; border: thin ridge grey; }
th { background: #0046c3; color: #fff; max-width: 400px; padding: 5px 10px; }
td { font-size: 11px; padding: 5px 20px; color: #000; }
tr { background: #b8d1f3; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background: #dae5f4; }
tr:nth-child(odd) { background: #b8d1f3; }
.finished {color: green;}
.failed {color: red;} 
</style>
<title>
Report
</title>
"@
```

Then I create object to store the information:

```
$thisnode = New-Object PSObject
Add-Member -InputObject $thisnode -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Customer -Value $Customer
Add-Member -InputObject $thisnode -MemberType NoteProperty -Name NodeName -Value $node.hostname
Add-Member -InputObject $thisnode -MemberType NoteProperty -Name last_backup -Value $node.d2dLastBackupStartTime
Add-Member -InputObject $thisnode -MemberType NoteProperty -Name last_backup_activity -Value $node.d2dLastBackupJobStatus
Add-Member -InputObject $thisnode -MemberType NoteProperty -Name url -Value $URI
$failed += $thisnode
```

I convert the object to html

```
$htmlreport = $failed | Sort-Object Customer, last_backup | ConvertTo-Html -Head $header -Body "<H1>Failed</H1>"
```

I want to make the URL colomn as a link but found no solution

Comment: To clarify, you want the `https://localhost:8015/services...` items to become links instead of just text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a list of URLs into clickable HTML links using ConvertTo-HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652761/convert-a-list-of-urls-into-clickable-html-links-using-convertto-html)

Comment: @JamesC. yea thats true.

Comment: Maybe this command will help for a solution. `$URI = "https://"+$Server+":$port/services/UDPService?wsdl"`

Comment: `ConvertTo-Html` will still treat your link as text, it doesn't know what a url is and will never convert them to a link by itself. Look at the question Manu linked to, that is the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quick fix:

change

```
Add-Member -InputObject $thisnode -MemberType NoteProperty -Name url -Value $URI
```

to

```
Add-Member -InputObject $thisnode -MemberType NoteProperty -Name url -Value "<a href='$URI'>$URI</a>"
```

and append this after the `$htmlreport`-line:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($htmlreport) | Out-File C:\temp\htmlreport.html
```